# Should I master maven or start learning gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build

The project I'm working on uses Maven as a build tool. I know the basic concepts like profiles, pom inheritance, modules, plugins, goals, phases and so on the surface, but I'm still missing the true craftsmanship to implement complicated builds from a starch for different environments.

Now, should I become Maven expert or start learning Gradle instead of unveiling all technical nuances of Maven?

I don't see what value Gradle brings on the table. It is configured programmatically, but could this actually be evil? I have worked in Javascript world and used tools like Gulp and Webpack. The programmatic configuration in those tools was just a horrible mess and lacked consistency. It wasn't possible to form a clear mental picture of the configuration, as it was dynamic code, not a static document. When you had to make a change, it wasn't so obvious where to find that line of code handling that functionality. Well defined XML document is self describing, organized and easily grepable.

Also, by programmatic configuration, there is a higher change to introduce bug in the build itself. Will there be a time, when builds become so complex that it's necessary to build the build configuration of the project?

Considering these aspects, is there some pragmatic reason start using Gradle (other than following the trend)?

Comment: From my understanding you can use Maven and Gradle together. So maybe start mastering both?

Answer (score 1):

We evaluated Gradle vs. Maven for our company. Our experience:

Maven forces you to use a standardized approach to a build. The advantage is that the build scripts are more coherent in your company and also more like "everywhere else in the industry". The main disadvantage is that it is hard to configure custom needs, which often come from legacy approaches that you still need to support.

But there are also important usability aspects because the IDE support is quite different for the two build tools.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see what value Gradle brings on the table. It is configured programmatically, but could this actually be evil? I have worked in Javascript world and used tools like Gulp and Webpack. The programmatic configuration in those tools was just a horrible mess and lacked consistency.

The difference is: Javascript, Gulp and Webpack are ment to build Applications with lots of functionality and high complexity (OK, they are *used* to do that...)

Gradle is just to control the build process, a scripting environment like bash or PowerShell, but specialised to its field.

So IMHO you should start learning gradle, but keep your knowledge of maven...